# Can I use Visual Studio Community edition for testing projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I've started doing test automation for my employer with Visual studio express but very soon realized that it does not have good plugin support. Now i'm planning to move away from it and after reading about Community version I think this is the best option to go.

However, I'm not really sure on the licensing terms, it does say that I can't use it for commercial purposes but I'm just doing test automation for my employer which I'm sure will not be sold, does it still gets counted as commercial development ?
If not then can I use Visual studio Community version ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing issues are off-topic on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [website](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/):

> An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual
> Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning
> environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source
> projects.
>
> For all other usage scenarios:
>
> In non-enterprise
> organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In
> enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million
> US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open
> source, academic research, and classroom learning environment
> scenarios described above.

So you're allowed to use it in an enterprise if you're contributing to open source, research or teaching; or are a company with less than 250 PCs and under $1,000,000 in revenue and there are fewer than 5 users working with it

Comment: So, i can't use it as in my case my employer has more than 250 PCs :(